# Excel - choose random string from list of strings not including an existing string

Tags: excel

I am automating the comments for some test marking, and I wanted to give a bit of variety to the comments I give for correct answers, so I have used the following formula:

`=IF(E5=1,CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,4),"Great work!","Excellent work!","Great job!","Well done!"),"")`

Here, if the answer is correct, then cell `E5` is set to 1, and it chooses from one of 4 comments and leaves an empty string otherwise.

This works fine, but the test has two questions, and I would prefer it if when both questions are correct, they don't receive the same comment.

For example, if the formula above is in cell `E11` and `E16=1` indicates question 2 is correct, then I would like to do something along the lines of:

`=IF(E16=1,IF(E11="",CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,4),"Great work!","Excellent work!","Great job!","Well done!"),CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,3),[set difference of original strings and string in E11])),"")`

In plain english: Given question 2 is correct, but question 1 is not, to determine the comment for question 2 just select a random comment from the list; however, if both questions are correct, then the comment for question 2 must be randomly selected from the original list, not including the comment that was given for question 1 (no duplicates).

..but I'm not sure how to make that work in Excel.

**EDIT:**

I know I could just have two disjoint lists of "correct" comments for each question so there would never be any duplicates, but I am just curious as to whether it is possible to do it this way using Excel or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can just filter out the phrase which has already been used:

```
=LET(congrats,{"Great work!","Excellent work!","Great job!","Well done!"},
filterCongrats,FILTER(congrats,congrats<>E11),
IF(E16=1,INDEX(filterCongrats,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(filterCongrats))),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, I didnt realise you could do in-line filtering like that, thanks heaps!